# IAM role is not authorized to perform ec2messages:GetMessages

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've created a role with an attached Policy "AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore":

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
                "ssm:GetDeployablePatchSnapshotForInstance",
                "ssm:GetDocument",
                "ssm:DescribeDocument",
                "ssm:GetManifest",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:ListAssociations",
                "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
                "ssm:PutInventory",
                "ssm:PutComplianceItems",
                "ssm:PutConfigurePackageResult",
                "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage",
                "ec2messages:DeleteMessage",
                "ec2messages:FailMessage",
                "ec2messages:GetEndpoint",
                "ec2messages:GetMessages",
                "ec2messages:SendReply"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And Trust relationships:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've then attached the IAM role to the instance. When I start the SSM agent in the instance I get the following error:

```
2022-03-16 23:14:49 ERROR [HandleAwsError @ awserr.go.49] [ssm-agent-worker] [MessageService] [MDSInteractor] error when calling AWS APIs. error details - GetMessages Error: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXX:assumed-role/SSMandCloudWatch/i-YYYYY is not authorized to perform: ec2messages:GetMessages on resource: arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:XXXX:* with an explicit deny in a service control policy
        status code: 400, request id: zzzz
```

The call it's complaining about is explicitly allowed in the policy. I've tried restarting the agent but didn't make any difference.

Comment: There is probably a Service Control Policies (SCP) defined at organization level denying the access. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html

Answer (score 1):

AWS permission evaluation can be complex. I like this [AWS diagram](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/implement-read-only-service-control-policy-in-aws-organizations/) below, so it is a good one to follow to track down permissions issues.

[image: AWS Permission Flow Diagram]

So there are a few other things to check or be aware of that could still be limiting access.